# Include 0 in count(*) SQL query

Tags: sql

I have two entities, `User` and `MaBase`. `MaBase` contains `user_id` and `status`. I want to get the count of `status` by user, I also want to show a `0` for any status values where the user doesn't have a record.

I created the below query using `count`, but it only returns non-null values. How I can solve this:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(*) 
FROM ma_base 
WHERE ma_base.user_id = 5 
GROUP BY status
```

I have 5 types of `status` values. If a user only has `ma_base` records for 4 of them, I still want to see a `0` value for the 5th status.

Comment: Sample data ans expected results would help here

Comment: Table on the left with all possible values. Left join to the real data.

Comment: @Sami how can i show you data that i have in my database because am using wamp

Comment: @shawnt00 can you please correct that query for me because i've also tried using left join but it didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not every day I get to write a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.ID, s.status, 
    coalesce((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ma_base m WHERE m.User_Id = u.ID and m.status = s.Status),0) As Status_Count
FROM User u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM MA_Base) s
WHERE u.ID = 5
```

OR:

```
SELECT u.ID, s.status, COALESCE(COUNT(m.status), 0) AS Status_Count
FROM User u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM MA_Base) s
LEFT JOIN MA_Base m ON m.User_Id = u.ID AND m.status = s.status
WHERE u.ID = 5
GROUP BY u.ID, s.status
```

In a nutshell, we first need to create a projection for the user with every possible status value, to anchor the result records for your "missing" statuses. Then we can `JOIN` or do a correlated subquery to get your desired results.

For the `JOIN` option, note the expression in the `COUNT()` function. It's important; `COUNT(*)` won't do what you want. For both options, note the use of `COALESCE()` to put the expected result in for `NULL`.

If you have a separate table defining your `status` values, use that instead of deriving them from `ma_base`.

Comment: I hope you have an index on status because the inner select will scan the whole table.

Comment: Wrapping `count` with `coalesce` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Conffusion Hence the recommendation in the last sentence.

Comment: @Joel indeed. I have no doubt you are aware of this. I made the point to warn the OP. Although the OP question makes complete sense, I agree we don't use a lot CROSS JOIN.